# Find the maximum of $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4$

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation, contest-math

Given $x_k\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=0\quad\text{and}\quad\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2=n^2-n$$
Find the maximum of
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4$$
I have notice that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=0$ implies that
$$x_m^2=\bigg(\sum_{\substack{k=1\\ k\not=m}}^n x_k\bigg)^2\leq (n-1)\sum_{\substack{k=1\\ k\not=m}}^n x_k^2=(n-1)(n^2-n-x_m^2)$$
using Chebyshev's inequality and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2=n^2-n$. Therefore we obtain $nx_m^2\leq n(n-1)^2\Leftrightarrow x_m\leq n-1$. Hence we have
\begin{align*}\begin{split}&\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-n+1)(x_k+1)^2\leq0\\ \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3 &\leq (n-3)\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n (n-1)\quad\text{since}\;\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=0 \\ &= n(n-1)(n-2)=(n-1)^3-(n-1)\end{split}\end{align*}
since I notice that $(x_k+1)^2$ would result me with an optimal, but I have no idea why is it so. Now using a similar approach, we find that
\begin{align*}\begin{split}&\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k^2-(n-1)^2)(x_k+1)^2\leq0 \\ \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4 &\leq-2\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3+(n^2-2n)\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n (n^2-2n+1)\\ &=-2\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3+(n^2-2n)(n^2-n)+n(n^2-2n+1)\end{split}\end{align*}
and I have no idea to how to proceed from here since I do not know the minimum of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3$ but I would like to give a guess that the maximum of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4$ is $(n-1)^4+(n-1)$.

Comment: Where is this problem from? What tools are allowed?

Comment: I guess it is probably a problem proposed by a teacher in China.

Comment: You wrote "I notice that $(x_k+1)^2$ would result me with an optimal, but I have no idea why is it so." The reason is that $-1 = x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{n-1} = -x_n/(n-1)$ is a constellation of $\{x_k\}$ which produces the maximum. Therefore, the factor $(x_k +1)^2$ which you used is zero at the maximum, which makes the total used sum $\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-n+1)(x_k+1)^2$ zero at the maximum, since  also $(x_k-n+1) =0$ for $x_n$, say. Hence the inequality you used,   $\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-n+1)(x_k+1)^2 \le 0$, is actually tight. So this approach gives the optimum since it 'mimics' the equality case.

Answer (score 4):

It looks smart at the first glance to use $(x_k^2-(n-1)^2)(x_k+1)^2\leq0$, but it would not get you to anywhere. In this case the equity holds at $x_1=1-n$, and $x_2=\cdots=x_n=1$, therefore we obtain $x_m\geq1-n$, hence we have
\begin{align*}\begin{split}&\qquad\qquad\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k+n-1)^2(x_k-1)^2\geq 0\\ \therefore \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4 &\leq (4-2n)\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^3-(n^2-6n+6)\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2-\sum_{k=1}^n (n^2-2n+1)\\ &\leq (4-2n)(-(n-1)^3+(n-1))-(n^2-6n+6)(n^2-n)-n(n^2-2n+1)\\ &= n^4-4n^3+6n^2-3n=(n-1)^4+(n-1)\end{split}\end{align*}
Not too sure if this is the solution since the inequality is flip yet I have no reason for that, maybe it is because of the $x_k^3$. Another thing to consider is that $x_m\geq1-n\Leftrightarrow x_m^3\geq(1-n)^3=-(n-1)^3$, one may also try using the fact that $x_m^3+(n-1)^3\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is an "easy" solution in the sense of the OP's attempt, or similar.

I will present here a more general solution which is based on Problem 2.98 in Vasile Cirtoaje's book "Mathematical Inequalities Vol.1" (Ploiesti, Romania 2015). Vasile Cirtoaje, also known as Vasc in various communities, has generated this problem himself in 2010, and Vasc's problems tend to be somewhat tricky...

Ok, the general statement which can be proved is:
Given $x_k\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=0\quad\text{and fixed}\quad R^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2$$
the maximum of
$\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4$ is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4 \le \tfrac{n^2-3n+3}{n(n-1)} R^4 = [(n-1)^4 + n-1] \Big[ \tfrac{R^2}{n(n-1)} \Big]^2 \quad \tag{1}
$$
with equality for $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{n-1} = -x_n/(n-1) = \frac{R}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}$ or permutations and negations  thereof.
Whereas the first formulation of the RHS of (1) is more compact, the second maybe is more intuitive, as it mimics the structure of the equality case with the "counting term" $[(n-1)^4 + n-1] $, multiplied with the "base unit" in the  equality case which is $x_i^2 = \tfrac{R^2}{n(n-1)}$.

In the case given in the OP's task here, we are given $R^2 = n(n-1)$ and that means that
$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^4 \le (n-1)^4 + n-1
$
with equality for $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{n-1} = -x_n/(n-1) = 1$, which is exactly which was conjectured by OP.

PROOF:

W.l.o.g., let the largest $x_n^2 \ge x_k^2 \quad \forall k\ne n $. Consider
$$
S^2 = \tfrac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k^2
$$
We have that  $S^2 \le x_n^2$. Further, using Chebychev's sum inequality and $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k=0$, we have
$$
S^2 \ge \tfrac{1}{(n-1)^2}(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}x_k)^2 = \frac{x_n^2}{(n-1)^2}
$$
Now consider
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k^4 = (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k^2)^2 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j>k}^{n-1} x_j^2 x_k^2$$
There are $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ terms in the double sum. By Cauchy-Schwarz, this gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k^4 \le  (n-1)^2 S^4 - \tfrac{4}{(n-1)(n-2)} [\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j>k}^{n-1} x_j x_k ]^2 \\
= (n-1)^2 S^4 - \tfrac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)} [(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k)^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_k^2]^2 \\
=
(n-1)^2 S^4 - \tfrac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)} [x_n^2 - (n-1)S^2]^2
$$
Adding $x_n^4$ and inserting the conjectured maximum gives that it is enough to prove
$$
x_n^4 + 
(n-1)^2 S^4 - \tfrac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)} [x_n^2 - (n-1)S^2]^2 \le \tfrac{n^2-3n+3}{n(n-1)} R^4 = \tfrac{n^2-3n+3}{n(n-1)} [x_n^2 + (n-1)S^2]^2
$$
Bringing everything on one side and clearing denominators gives
$$
n(n-1)(n-2)x_n^4 + 
n(n-1)^3(n-2) S^4 - n [x_n^2 - (n-1)S^2]^2 - (n^2-3n+3)(n-2) [x_n^2 + (n-1)S^2]^2 \le 0
$$
Opening the brackets and factorizing shows that the LHS can be written:
$$
2 (n-1)(n-3)(S^2-x_n^2)((n-1)^2S^2-x_n^2) \le 0
$$
Now this is true for $n\ge 3$  and since we already observed that
$S^2 \le x_n^2$ and $(n-1)^2 S^2 - x_n^2 \ge 0$. The latter is actually zero in  the equality case, which makes the approach tight.

The case $n=2$ is obvious since
$$
x_1^4 + x_2^4 = \frac12 (x_1^2 + x_2^2)^2 + \frac12 (x_1 +x_2)^2 (x_1 -x_2)^2 = \frac{R^4}{2}
$$

This concludes the proof. $\qquad \Box$